# Is it possible to use Snap inside an SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am following the tutorial at https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/135-three-ways-animate-svg/ and I'm trying to put everything inside an svg but the js part uses Snap and doesn't work.

I tried

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="robot" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 127.9 178.4" enable-background="new 0 0 127.9 178.4" xml:space="preserve">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js">

var s = Snap("#robot");

var leftPupil = s.select("#left-pupil");

leftPupil.attr({
  fill: "green"
});

leftPupil.animate({
  r: 50,
  fill: "lightgreen"
}, 1000);

</script>
</svg>
```

but the console says Snap is not defined. Is it possible to load it in some way just using SVG?

Comment: <script src="some url"></script>
<script>

some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<script>` tag inside a  `<svg>` element is from the SVG namespace and uses the `href` attribute (or `xlink:href` if you adhere to SVG 1.1) instead of `src`. In addition, like johnheroy said, take care to use separate elements for each script.

```
<svg id="robot" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ...>
<script xlink:href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js" />
<!-- grafic content -->
<script>
var s = Snap("#robot");
//...
</script>
</svg>
```

Comment: I also tried as you suggested but still couldn't make it work. Here is the code I tried https://jsfiddle.net/tzuya/3dfvtq4y/1/

Comment: Position the script at the end of the document. At time of parsing, the selected elemenent does not yet exist. (There still remains an error _'rgb(0, 128, 0)' is not a valid selector_ in the animation of the color, but I can't help you with that.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the SnapSVG library in a separate `<script>` tag from the one where you defined your own code. So try closing the first `<script>` tag and then opening a new one for your code, i.e.:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script>
    // your JS code
</script>
```